# Symfony: Using JavaScript in a onChange-event in a form and calling an action from the JS-Function

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony-1.4

I never used Javascript before but now I need it in my Symfony-Project (Symfony 1.4) and have some problems about where to add code to get it working:

I have a template (indexSuccess) in the module „aktionLimit“ where I show the values of the variables of an Object of the class „Aktion“ :

```
<p>Value1: <?php echo $aktion->getValue1()  ?></p>
<p>Value2: <?php echo $aktion->getValue2()  ?></p>
<p>Value3: <?php echo $aktion->getValue3()  ?></p>

<?php include_partial('form', array('form' => $form)) ?>
```

This is the executeIndex:

```
$this->aktion = AktionlimitPeer::getByName($this->getUser()->getAttribute('aktion'));

$aktionParam = new Aktion();
$aktionParam->setName($this->aktion->getName());

$this->form = new AktionlimitForm(array(), array("aktion" => $aktionParam));
```

The AktionLimitForm looks like this:

```
$aktionForm = new AktionForm($this->getOption('aktion'), array("limit" => true));

$this->embedForm('Aktion', $aktionForm);  

$this->widgetSchema['neuerWert']= new sfWidgetFormInputText();
```

The embedded AktionForm has just one element (a dropdown-box which includes the unique names of the objects of „Aktion“):

```
$this->widgetSchema['name'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' =>   AktionPeer::getTypes()),array('onchange' => '???'));
```

Whenever the user chooses another „aktion“ in the dropdown-box I want to load the current object „aktion“ (referenced by the name) in executeIndex and show its values (Value 1-3) in indexSuccess.(When submitting it leads to another action.)

I need a function which calls executeIndex in the onChange-Event. I probably have to declare the function in the web/js-folder, is this right?. But how do I call the function from the form? And how do I call an action in a JavaScript-Function?

I hope you understood what I've written – today I have some difficulties to explain this problem in English :) Could anybody help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, consider upgrading to symfony 2.

Then, you don't need to configure this in the form type, if you decide to use jquery (nice javascript framework). with jquery you can bind events to elements very easy.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#id_of_the_form_field').change(function() {
        // to get the selected value
        var selected = $(this).val()

        // do your magic pony stuff
    });
});
```

To call your php actions from javascript, you need to make a ajax request to related route.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your help! Everything works except displaying the new values. The template gets the right values (I logged it in the template) but they aren't displayed. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't know, you show too less of your code, I don't know your javascript and i also don't know what really your goal is ^^